# Add class to element when clicked elsewhere + condition on class presence

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a sliding menu with sub-menus. I'm trying to hide an element in the navigation row when a user clicks one of the parent menu item that has a sub-menu (clicks on the expand arrow) + I want to show back the hidden element when the users clicks back to the top-level menu.
My menu's `<ul>` element get's a class of `slide-menu-is-active-parent` when any of the sub-menus is open.

This is a simple version of my row html:

```html
<div class="navigation row">
  <nav>
    <ul id="nav-menu">
      <li>Menu item 1</li>
        <span class="submenu-button">
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>Sub-menu item 1</li>
          <li>Sub-menu item 2</li>
          <li>Sub-menu item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Menu item 2</li>
        <span class="submenu-button">
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>Sub-menu item 1</li>
          <li>Sub-menu item 2</li>
          <li>Sub-menu item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="content-row">
  [whatever content...]
</div>
```

I tried the following script to add a class od `menu-open` to the `some-content` element when both conditions are met: the user clicks on the sub-menu button and when the `<ul id="nav-menu">` element get's the `slide-menu-is-active-parent` class when opened. And with the class added to my content row, I could use simple `.content-row.menu-open{display:none}` to hide it.

```
function($) {
    $("#nav-menu .submenu-button").click(function(){
        if ($('#nav-menu').hasClass('slide-menu-is-active-parent')) {
            $('.content-row').addClass('menu-open');
        } else {
            $('.content-row').removeClass('menu-open');
        }
    });  
});
```

But that doesn't work. Any tips on where my script is lacking?

Comment: difficult to solve without an [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Could you add a jsfiddle, codepen or stackblitz?

Comment: your HTML is invalid - you close the `li` elements twice and do not close the `ul` element; also do not close the `nav`

Comment: You have two `<ul id="nav-menu">` both of which you never close.

Comment: right, sorry for the wrong markup - I've corrected it adding proper closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, your code works: just add the `slide-menu-is-active-parent` class to the `#nav-menu`, and the `content-row` shows up on click. Still, I would do this differently - even if using `jQuery`. Here's a simplistic solution:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // this click handler opens the sub-menu
  $(".menu-item").on('click', function() {
    $(this).find(".sub-menu").toggle()
  })

  // this click handler toggles the content-row
  $(".sub-menu > li").on('click', function(e) {
    // stopPropagation prevents the click event
    // to bubble up to the menu-item parent
    e.stopPropagation()
    $(".content-row").toggle()
  })
})
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}

.menu-item,
.sub-menu>li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content-row {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation row">
  <nav>
    <ul id="nav-menu">
      <li class="menu-item">Menu item 1
        <ul class="sub-menu d-none">
          <li>Sub-menu item 1</li>
          <li>Sub-menu item 2</li>
          <li>Sub-menu item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">Menu item 2
        <ul class="sub-menu d-none">
          <li>Sub-menu item 1</li>
          <li>Sub-menu item 2</li>
          <li>Sub-menu item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="content-row d-none">
  [whatever content...]
</div>
```

Comment: Great thing you fixed OP's invalid markup! You should really point that out.

Comment: @connexo thx! I commented the problems on the original question.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [$(this)](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#using-dom-elements) to refer to the element you clicked.

You also need to find parent with class, so you can use [parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) with the name of your class.

NOTE : if i solved your problem, please next time do effort to make your question more clear, it will be better for everyone :)

```js
$("#nav-menu .submenu-button").click(function(){
    if ($(this).parents('#nav-menu').hasClass('slide-menu-is-active-parent')) {
      $('.content-row').addClass('menu-open');
    } else {
      $('.content-row').removeClass('menu-open');
    }
});
```

```css
.content-row { display:none }
.menu-open { display:block }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation row">
  <nav>
    <ul id="nav-menu" class="slide-menu-is-active-parent">
      <li>Menu item 1</li>
      <span class="submenu-button">Button</span>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Sub-menu item 1</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item 2</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item 3</li>
      </ul>
      <li>Menu item 2</li>
      <span class="submenu-button">Button</span>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Sub-menu item 1</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item 2</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="content-row">
  [whatever content...]
</div>
```

Comment: based on the question, no `this` or `parents` is needed - OP did not state that different content should be displayed in the `content-row`, or anything like that. The condition is just a static check with `hasClass` on a static selector.

Comment: The HTML in this answer is also invalid.

Comment: @connexo i just pay attention trying to solve his problem, not to the w3c validation...